# How to get the function name while in a function for debug strings?

Tags: c++, debugging, qt

I want to output the function name each time it is called, I can easily copy and paste the function name, however I wondered if there was a shortcut that would do the job for me?

At the moment I am doing:

```
SlideInfoHeader* lynxThreeFile::readSlideInfoHeader(QDataStream & in)
{
    qDebug("lynxThreeFile::readSlideInfoHeader");
}
```

but what I want is something generic:

```
SlideInfoHeader* lynxThreeFile::readSlideInfoHeader(QDataStream & in)
{
    qDebug(this.className() + "::" + this.functionName());
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"`__FUNCTION__`" is supported by both MSVC and GCC and should give you the information you need.

Comment: Hadn't realized it was supported on MSVC

Comment: It was supported from VC7.  Version 6 did not support "__FUNCTION__"

Answer (score 14):

I see from your example that you are using [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). In which case your best bet is to use `Q_FUNC_INFO` found in `<QGlobal>`. Here's the description:

> Expands to a string that describe the
>   function the macro resides in. How
>   this string looks more specifically is
>   compiler dependent. With GNU GCC it is
>   typically the function signature,
>   while with other compilers it might be
>   the line and column number.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using gcc you may find `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` more to your liking.

Answer (score 6):

**`__func__`** is c99 ( which does in turn mean it might not work with visual studio - but hey it's standard :o) )

**`__FUNCTION__`** works pretty much everywhere

**`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`** is gnu specific and returns the full qualified name with (namespaces?), classname, returntype, functionname, parameterslist

Answer (score 5):

If you check out boost there is a macro BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION that is portable across platforms. In the C99 standard there is a compiler variable `__func__` that has the desired effect. I believe has been accepted into the C++0x standard. A reasonable number of compilers will already support this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c++20 you can call method `function_name()` in namespace `std::source_location` [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/function_name)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <source_location>

void foo(double &&) { 
    auto cc=std::source_location::current().function_name();
    std::puts(cc);  
}
 
int main(int, char const* const[])
{
    foo(42);
}
```

[works on gcc 11.1](https://godbolt.org/z/j1noq1qzo)