# How to get function name in function Qt

Tags: qt, logging, metaobject

I try to make log when something is wrong, so I want to write the class info and function name like this:

```
void MainWindowTest::testMethod()
{
    qDebug()<<QString("ClassName is:%0,Function Name is:%1")
              .arg(this->metaObject()->className()).arg("how to get method name");
}
```

how to do this?

Comment: Well, since you are already in the method, you are able to just put in the method name. Put the string "testMethod".

Comment: My favorite method is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173821/how-to-get-the-function-name-while-in-a-function-for-debug-strings

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `Q_FUNC_INFO`

sample code:

```
qDebug() << "Function Name: " << Q_FUNC_INFO;
```

Refer [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#Q_FUNC_INFO)

Answer (score 0):

QT_STRINGIFY

```
MainWindowVM::MainWindowVM(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    QDebug() << QT_STRINGIFY(MainWindowVM);
}
```

Comment: Better to use QT_STRINGIFY becouse is dot not catch method return type